# How to difference b/w two dates and get result in hour mininutes and seconds in JavaScript

Tags: react-native

How to difference b/w two dates and get result in hour mininutes and seconds.

const actualTime = data.actualTimeIn;
const currunTime = moment(new Date()).format();

```
 //Actual TIME IS: 2023-02-23T10:50:51.755Z
 //cURRUNT TIME IS: 2023-02-23T16:32:00+05:30
 console.log("MY ACTUALTIME", actualTime);
 console.log("MY CURRUNT TIME", currunTime);

 var duration = moment.duration(moment(currunTime).diff(actualTime));
```

I try to implement using moment but not working how to fix it,

I want my final result is diffhours, diffmoniutes and diffseconds

Answer (score 0):

You can calcuclate the diff duration as follows.
You should think of using https://date-fns.org/ as moment is no longer maintained.

```js
const actualTime = new Date("2023-02-21T10:50:51.755Z")
const currenTime = new Date("2023-02-23T12:50:52.755Z")

var diff = moment.duration(moment(currenTime).diff(actualTime))
var diffFormated = moment.utc(diff.as('milliseconds')).format('HH:mm:ss')
console.log('duration: ', diffFormated);

// In case you want the total diff use as(Hours|Minutes|...)
console.log('hours: ', diff.asHours());
console.log('minutes: ', diff.asMinutes());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ACTUAL TIME IS 2023-02-24T04:34:39.884+05:30
CURRUNT TIME 2023-02-24T10:16:13+05:30
DIFFERANCE B/W TWO DATES 18:18:26

but actual result according to above is 6 hours, so this is wrong time 18:18:26 occur.
How to check formate date also means DD:MM:YY HH:mm:ss can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: How to get difference b/w 2 dates in DD:MM:YY:HH:MM:SS

Comment: Just flip currentTime and actualTime ```moment.duration(moment(currenTime).diff(actualTime))```

Comment: example if the clockin is 3 days ago from today then time will be 72:56:59 something like this right?

How to calculate this??

Comment: I updated my Snippet, the ```diff.asHours()``` return the total diff ans hours without respecting daytime